# Is citrix netscalar restricted solely to servers running Citrix?

Tags: citrix, netscaler

I understand that Citrix NetScaler usually sits in front of citrix servers. Does it also sit in front of non-citrix servers?

Answer (score 1):

*>Does it also sit in front of non-citrix servers?*

Yes. It is a full-blown load balancer. Or using the newer, fancier, term an "Application Delivery Controller".

It will do all the typical work

- distributing to backend
- monitoring backend (using several included service monitors)
- arrange persistence to backend
- offload authentication to frontend and authenticate to backend
- offload SSL/TLS from backend

And also:

- SSL-VPN gateway
- Web cache
- Web front end optimization (compression, JavaScript-minification, Sharding, etc.)
- Web application firewall

There are several editions and only the most expensive one will give you all the features. Also SSL-VPN is licensed by concurrent users.

Answer (score -1):

It can be used for all other servers for various purposes.

Answer (score -1):

depends on how its configurated, you can use for Loadbalancing level 4( At Layer 4, a load balancer has visibility on network information such as application ports and protocol (TCP/UDP), Reverse Proxy, Storage, etc.